# shared variables with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

From the official documentation of Spark:
"*Spark does provide two limited types of shared variables for two common usage patterns: broadcast variables and accumulators.*"

(http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#shared-variables)

However, "*Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a **read-only** variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks.*"

What I want is a "*broadcast **read-write** variable*", (I mean: a shared variable that all workers and driver can access and modify !) is there any way to do it ?! thanks

Comment: This would be possible with some hackery in the source, however it would require a lot of locking to deal with concurrent writes. In short this is NOT a good idea and is why it is not supported. What are you trying to accomplish? Most likely you can do it without variable mutation

Comment: In fact, the thing that led me to reflect on shared variables is that I have a complex object on which the workers will have to work (this object is initialized at the driver and passed to workers)... my problem is that Spark creates new objects and sends them to workers and thus I can not retrieve the final result of the workers at the driver, that's why I thought why not create a shared variable at driver level and pass it to the workers who will work on it, and at the end I can have their result (the final result-the updated object- not the first one -the initialized one-) at the driver...

Comment: No, for that you're best bet is to send the pertinent data back and then reduce it to update the object with the results.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot exactly do this because the synchronization costs would be too high to allow each worker to have a consistent view of the variable. Your options are to either use a broadcast variable, which can be modified based on the results of an action in spark, or in an accumulator you can call getLocal value, but this only shows the local modifications made to the variable.

One way to achieve this with a lot of extra resources is use an external data store like voldemort, cassandra or Hbase

Comment: I like the idea of using an accumulator

Comment: @JustinPihony I mostly agree with your comment on the question, in that he probably should think of a different way to achieve what he wants

Answer (score 0):

Like any map-reduce or MPP application, there are multi containers / tasks, contexts. You understood, this is like X independent servers with a load-balancer in front!

So, like a web load balancer:

- 1) You could use sticky session, in Spark => group data by a key you want distribute
- 2) Or use Redis to have a common in-memory storage, slow but very powerful (or https://accumulo.apache.org/)

This is "funny" because it's a very common problem, with MR, Storm, PIG etc... never really resolved ;-(